# are TFTs meant to be used with VGA connection?

Tags: multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

I have two TFTs monitors, Dell and Lenovo.

When I use VGA connection from either the graphic card or the inbuilt VGA port, the screen on each display is fuzzy, blurry and text casts shadow on black backgrounds.

I looked it up online and some sites suggested that the conversion of the VGA analogue signal to digital might be the cause of the blur, which may be entirely true because whenever I use the monitors with a display port, the blur is zero on the screen and everything seems to be crisper and clear.

So why do TFT manufacturers include it as an option on the monitor when they know it will cause a blur on-screen due to the signal conversion on the monitor? And also will replacing the VGA connection with a DVI-D Dual Link 24-pin cable fix the blur?

I asked this because the VGA output port on my graphic card has been labeled CRT, which may be advising user to use the cable with a Cathode Ray Tube Screen. I know a CRT monitor will not show the fuzzy text because it is good with handling analog signals, so why do Monitor manufacturers still include an option they know will reduce image quality on the TFT?

Comment: VGA is an analog signal. When you connect a screen using the VGA adapter, always press the AUTO button on your monitors so it can auto-align. That should solve most of the blurry and fuzzy of the screen.

Comment: VGA has been used for years and there is no reason *not* to use it on a TFT, except for the fact that it, as you say, it has quality issues. The reason it is included is because it was fitted to every computer for literally decades. Recently it is more common to see machines without VGA, but up until a few years ago the connector was pretty much available on every computer on the planet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are describing is most likely caused due to the monitor not correctly auto-aligning on its own.

This is common for any digital screen that is connected through a VGA connector.

When a screen has a VGA connector, you can count on it that the screen should look good enough to be used.

If the text is blurry and casts shadows, then it is just a sign of pixels not aligning properly. Basically the screen projects the pixel of 0,0 but because it is misaligned, it projects this on both 0,0 and 0,1 for example, and pixels blend etc.

To fix this issue, just press the AUTO button on your monitor for each monitor connected to VGA. You'll see it saying Auto-adjusting... and then the image should pop straight into the screen. Make sure you have something on screen that has no black borders. Usually anything is okay.

You have have to repeat this process for every time you switch resolution to a new resolution the first time, but the screen should remember that resolution onwards.

That said, if the screen is set to a resolution the monitor officially doesn't support or is not the native resolution, it will already try to squeeze pixels together. This will also happen on a timing issue, for exeample, if the monitor is set to 59hz instead of 60hz. Changing the hz and resolution is done in windows though. After correcting this, press auto once more.

Comment: The model is a `Dell P2213`, I guess the Auto option is called `Auto Adjust`, i did exactly that and it is not working

Comment: Make sure you have something filling the entire screen and press it a few times. If that still doesn't work, make sure you set the screen to 60hz, not 59hz, and press auto again

Comment: Its not filling the entire screen, there is a black bar below the taskbar and the lower vertical end of the monitor and also on top

Comment: okay, doing what you have requested in the edit

Comment: Right, so its not auto-adjusting properly.  Make sure the refreshrate is set to a multiple of 30, 60hz is preferred here.

Comment: The nVidia card is not letting me change the resolution and refresh rate..The nVidia card got the wrong resolution, it says `1280*768` as the native resolution when the native resolution is `1680*1050`. Also it set the resolution to `72Hz` which is not a multiple of 30

Comment: Worked like a charm, everything is sharp and clearer except for flickering

Comment: What is the requirement for refresh rate to be a multiple of 30?

Comment: @user1686 - It’s just a default standard at least on computer monitors, due to NTSC and PAL, televisions evolved slightly different standards. Due to the extreme similarities to the actual panels themselves (on some case the exact same panel) televisions and monitors have started to support the same features.  This is the reason that 144 Hz panels have surfaced (but 120 Hz are also common)

Comment: @Ramhound: But 144 Hz is not a multiple of 30... I'm not up to modern standards, but I'm sure my Windows 98/2000 system already had 72 Hz and 85 Hz as a standard option back in the day (60 Hz on a CRT was literally headache-inducing). Probably every single system had those non-multiple-of-30 framerates as "default standard". Which is why I was asking LPChip about whether there's something special about it with LCDs.

Comment: The reason to choose 60hz is that almost all LCD's will support 60hz as a standard, where most only support 60hz. Given that you also had problems with the resolution AND the hz, means the display was not identified correctly. finding the right drivers for your display should correct that.

Comment: @LPChip - You said 60 Hz twice in your last comment.

Comment: @user1686 I asked for a multiple of 30 but technically that is indeed not correct. Most displays will support 30hz, 60hz natively, and onwards have weird ones only if those displays support it. 75hz, 90hz, 120hz, 144hz, 240hz, etc... The Dell P2213 only supports 60 I believe

Comment: @Ramhound yeah. I mean that all will support at least 60, maybe more, but most support just 60, but nothing else.

Comment: @user1686 - I don't see how that applies to a TFT monitor (which at the end of the day is an LCD monitor).  I couldn't speak to displays that supported 72 Hz and 85 Hz in the 1990s, can only speak to modern technologies directly.  The suggestion for 60 Hz was very purposeful, since it had the greatest chance of being supported, and indeed it was.

Answer (score 3):

All cables, analog or digital, have limited throughput - you can push only so much information through them per second until problems arise. "Information" here, in context of displays, means pixel color values at some resolution and refresh rate. The higher resolution and refresh rate, the more information there is to transmit.

With digital cables the throughput simply cannot be exceeded. The protocol defines valid parameter ranges and neither device will be able to break this barrier. There's a hard limit to what resolution and refresh rate combinations are possible on that link.

Analog cables are a different story. You may be able to get more out of them that they were designed for at the cost of quality. This does not mean that every receiving device will be able to work with such signal, but if both ends support it and you're okay with image deterioration, you're good.

The interesting thing about CRTs is that while their vertical resolution is discrete, the horizontal "resolution" is essentially infinite and we're using a discrete number only because it's the only practical way to handle it in a computer (TV is different). VGA's design reflects this: some signals in a VGA cable were supposed to directly drive the electron beam in a CRT. LCDs don't work like that though, they have a discrete resolution and no electron beam. The VGA signal has to be electronically sampled to recreate the discrete image the computer intended to display, and then send it to the LCD panel. While a CRT with its infinite horizontal resolution would be immune to any slight clock skew, the sampling is not, potentially degrading the quality further beyond cable's electrical limitations. This manifests as a horizontal color bleed.

With digital cables like DVI-D, HDMI and DP there's no digital-to-analog-to-digital conversion going on anymore, so you're either getting perfectly crisp image, or none at all if you're exceeding cable's capabilities.

Be careful with DVI, because there are three DVI variants that use the same cable. DVI-A is just VGA over a DVI cable, with all problems of regular VGA still there. DVI-D is 100% digital and compatible with HDMI through passive adapters. DVI-I is a mix of the two. With that last one usually only one type of signal will be used by the monitor, even though the cable carries both. Some (very old) LCDs ironically use only the analog component of DVI-I.

As to why VGA connections are still available on LCDs: because buyers sometimes still want to use them for various reasons.

Comment: Well explained, what about DVI-A which carries analog signal? Can it behave the same way as VGA?

Comment: @CodeTiger Yes, DVI-A is just VGA over a DVI cable. It's susceptible to all its problems. I'll edit the answer to clarify.

Comment: Okay, you for that information

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: It’s for compatibility. Use DVI if you can.

VGA connectors on displays are becoming obsolete quickly on consumer-grade flat panel displays. VGA is not suitable for 4K resolution or higher refresh rates. PCs and laptops mostly don’t have VGA connectors anymore either.

When flat panel displays were new, the opposite was true; many graphics cards, especially in office PCs, would not have digital outputs (DVI back then). That’s why cheap flat panel displays often only had VGA connectors.

When using the VGA connection with a specific source and display mode (resolution, color depth, refresh rate) for the first time, make sure to press the “Auto” button. Every flat panel display with VGA inputs has one. Make sure all edges and corners are showing bright colors, so the display can accurately measure the signal geometry.

If you can, however, you should use a digital display connection like DVI, HDMI or DisplayPort. There’s some compatibility between DVI and HDMI, too, so cheap passive adapters are available.

So yes, if you can use a DVI cable (both display and PC compatible), go for it!

Comment: When pressing the AUTO button, you should make sure that you have some program running full screen with some kind of colour displayed. Having large black areas at the top may fool the monitor into thinking your screen is shorter than it is and result in the calibration not going as well as you'd like.

Comment: Thanks, was about to ask another related question but lemme ask a new one

Answer (score 0):

This does not aound like abything to do with tft technology, and everything to do with the signal being received.  Have you tried an alternative cable and made sure the computer and monitor are grounded to a commin ground?  (It could also be the video card output)